# Pagina Jsf cadastro de lançamentos

Tags: jsf

Estou estudando jsf, fiz uma pagina de cadastro de lançamento, porém quando eu insiro os dados e clico no botão pra cadastrar está ocorrendo o erro abaixo, alguém podem me ajudar

> HTTP Status 500 - /CadastroLancamento.xhtml @44,41
>   value="#{cadastroLancamentoBean.lancamento.descricao}": Target
>   Unreachable, identifier 'cadastroLancamentoBean' resolved to null
>
> type Exception report
>
> message /CadastroLancamento.xhtml @44,41
>   value="#{cadastroLancamentoBean.lancamento.descricao}": Target
>   Unreachable, identifier 'cadastroLancamentoBean' resolved to null
>
> description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it
>   from fulfilling this request.
>
> exception
>
> javax.servlet.ServletException: /CadastroLancamento.xhtml @44,41
>   value="#{cadastroLancamentoBean.lancamento.descricao}": Target
>   Unreachable, identifier 'cadastroLancamentoBean' resolved to null
>     javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:606)
>     org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>   root cause
>
> javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /CadastroLancamento.xhtml @44,41
>   value="#{cadastroLancamentoBean.lancamento.descricao}": Target
>   Unreachable, identifier 'cadastroLancamentoBean' resolved to null
>     com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getType(TagValueExpression.java:100)
>     com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicInputRenderer.getConvertedValue(HtmlBasicInputRenderer.java:95)

Comment: Robson, Seria melhor se postasse seu código, mas você pode começar verificando se o Managed Bean está anotado com @ManagedBean, se o objeto <lancamento> está declarado no Managed Bean cadastroLancamentoBean, se ele possui os métodos getters e os setters criados e se você instanciou o objeto (Lancamento lancamento = New Lancamento();). Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: Leo obrigado pela força, como estou estudando fiquei horas tentando achar o que poderia ser ai simplesmente eu fechei o eclipse e abri dinovo e deu certo acredita, não sei se foi algum conflito ou tal sou novo no java ai no começo é dificil, mas vlw pela força.

Comment: Dê clean no seu projeto, `maven install` e depois `update maven project`.